# How do can you show an external application window within VSCode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm looking into creating a VS Code extension where it will automatically run a device simulator from an exe for debugging. If possible, it would be nice if the simulator can be displayed within VS Code itself.

I haven't made a VS Code extension before, so I'm unsure on the plausibility of this. Does anyone have any resources for implementation of displaying an external application into a view or have any suggested workarounds?

*For further context, this is for the Playdate Simulator.*

Comment: what is the UI of the application, VSC is HTML based, if you can tunnel/interface from/to HTML you might show the application in a Webview

Comment: @rioV8 Unfortunately I do not have access to the source code so it is unclear. I only have a '.exe' file. I think it's safe to assume that it isn't HTML based and is most likely using C.

Comment: it might have a socket interface, like debuggers

Comment: You cannot embed a native window into a webview (iframe), no way.